# Where can I obtain a SUBE card for the Buenos Aires Subte and Bus systems?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, argentina, buenos-aires

I know that it's possible for foreigners to obtain the RFID transit card SUBE but I don't know where to get it. It seems that it's not sold in all Subte stations.

Where can I get the SUBE card?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to go to a locutório (like a small shop).  It'll be called that - "Locutório" with a purple sign saying "SUBE" in the window.

Where are these shops? There's a handy website that [maps all of them in Buenos Ares](http://www.xcolectivo.com.ar/sube/puntosdeentrega.php).

Then according to a [blog on the subject](http://www.buenosairesorbust.com/2012/10/get-your-sube-card.html):

> You'll fill out a small application with your name, address, and
>   passport/DNI number and pay the $20 ARS. However, your card will not
>   come loaded with funds and the locutório may not charge SUBE cards. So
>   you will have to find a kiosko that does. There are many along Santa
>   Fe that sport the SUBE logo in their windows. These places may or may
>   not be able to charge your card at that time, so again, you'll just
>   have to ask. When you find a charging station, you can have up to $50
>   ARS put on the card at a time. The clerk will charge your card on a
>   space age sensor machine and hand you a receipt with the proof of
>   funds.

Comment: +1 Mark is right, basically it was an issue when the card came out, but nowadays you go to any kiosk or locutorio and they will sell you one or point you in the right direction. Usually close to big shopping malls you will find SUBE stands where you can get it

Comment: You might find this link useful http://www.sube.gob.ar/centros-de-carga/

Comment: I just spent a couple hours trying to buy one, everyone kept pointing me to Correos (post office) but they were all out. Everyone I've talked to at the shops says that it's a huge pain. I've tried a few locutorios, but will try some more when I go out next.

Comment: There are little shops inside shopping malls which Argentineans use to get their ID, they also have SUBE and as it is an official government shop they do have most of the time. You can find them in Paseo Alcorta and Alto Palermo (and probably any other big mall) They look like this http://www.transporte.gob.ar/UserFiles/imagenes.contenidos/noticias/315/3.jpg

Comment: Finally got it. There's an [official](http://www.sube.gob.ar/centros-de-obtencion) directory of all the "centros de obtención".

Answer (score 1):

You can get one in almost any corner(convenience) store that. They will either have a sign saying that they sell "tarjetas" or you can ask them.

FYI don't load too much money on your bus card at once as certain cards only work in certain cities.